# ReLearning: Using Git with remote repositories

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I have been JUST using git for some time in my organization. Suddenly the knowledge to understand git bit me.

So in the process, I understood that git can be standalone without requiring any repositories like Github or Gitlab, and solely be dependent on my single local machine.

My question is if the above is true, then what is the use of `git push, git fetch, git pull`.

If you argue that these commands were introduced to manage the online repositories, then how were initial developers used to collaborate without these online repositories, as Github was released around 2008.

Comment: Online can also mean network (intranet) ... where every programmer pulls from a git server in the network to his local machine. There is no need for Github and Gitlab ... they just show the things more 'beautiful'.

Comment: you can `git push|pull|fetch` a local remote (e.g. another directory on your computer with the same project) as well.

Comment: `git push` is just fetch + merge. The two interesting commands here are therefore just `git fetch` and `git push`. They have *your* Git call up some *other* Git. Your Git can then give commits to the other Git, or get commits from the other Git. GitHub are a "value added" re-seller: they (a) provide backed-up Git repositories that you can use in case your own Git repository is damaged, and (b) let you share with other users who can reach GitHub, but cannot reach your computer directly.

Comment: When you have your Git talk to some other Git, that other Git is simply a *peer*. It is not more authoritative than your Git. It is not *less* authoritative either. You can offer it commits, which it can accept or reject, and you can get commits from it, which you can use or discard. In the days before GitHub, people connected their systems, peer-to-peer, like this. That still works today. You can *treat* a GitHub or other repository as "the main one" but they're still just peers, as far as Git is concerned.

Answer (score 1):

Git can use four distinct protocols to transfer data: Local, HTTP, Secure Shell (SSH) and Git. More info at [Git Protocols](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols)

For remote access to a repository any internet accessible server with can be setup with HTTP, SSH or Git access.

The popular git portals such as github just provide an easy to use interface for git work.

Answer (score 1):

These commands are only used with a remote location.
In general `git` is a tool that needs a single location of the source code, at least at some point.
But you could still run your own server if you desire: [how-run-your-own-git-server](https://www.linux.com/learn/how-run-your-own-git-server)
I think for small companies or personal stuff it's way easier to let them get setup and maintained.
Not to forget about the wole open source community.